# Grid based fluid simulation errors

Tags: c++, simulation, fluid

So I am writing a fluid simulation based off of http://jamie-wong.com/2016/08/05/webgl-fluid-simulation/.

This is in C++.

The `class Grid` is just a class with the following:

```
Grid.data[][] : float[][] - floating point data
Grid.copy(): Grid -  creates a new grid with identical elements
Grid.set(int x,int y, float f): void - sets the data at (x,y)
Grid.operator() (int x,int y): float - gets the data at (x,y)
```

The reason this is a seperate class is so the Grid class can handle wrapping the coordinates around (I am too lazy for boundary conditions).

Advection:

```
void advect(Grid &from, Grid &to, Grid &vx, Grid &vy);
```

I know for sure that the advection function works perfectly.

These are the pressure and divergence functions:

```
void calcDivergence(Grid &density, Grid &divergence, Grid &vx, Grid &vy){
    for(int x=0;x<GRIDSIZE;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<GRIDSIZE;y++){
            divergence.set(x,y,  (-2/dt)*(vx(x+1,y)-vx(x-1,y)+vy(x,y+1)-vy(x,y-1))   );
        }
    }
}

void solvePressure(Grid &divergence, Grid &pressure){
    pressure.init();//set to 0
    Grid pressure0=pressure.copy();
    for(int i=0;i<PRESSURE_SOLVE_ITERS;i++){

        for(int x=0;x<GRIDSIZE;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<GRIDSIZE;y++){
                pressure.set(x,y,  (divergence(x,y)+pressure0(x-1,y)+pressure0(x+1,y)+pressure0(x,y-1)+pressure0(x,y+1))/4.0f   );
            }
        }

        pressure0=pressure.copy();

    }
}

void fixDivergence(Grid &pressure, Grid&vx, Grid &vy){
    for(int x=0;x<GRIDSIZE;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<GRIDSIZE;y++){
            float gradX=dt*0.5*(pressure(x+1,y)-pressure(x-1,y));
            float gradY=dt*0.5*(pressure(x,y+1)-pressure(x,y-1));
//            printf("%f,%f\n",gradX,gradY);//why is this zero?  solvePressure must be broken, check swap code
            vx.set(x,y,  vx(x,y)-gradX);
            vy.set(x,y,  vy(x,y)-gradY);
        }
    }
}
```

And for determining the accuracy of the pressure solver:

```
float pressureAccuracy(Grid &density, Grid &pressure){
    float f=0;
    for(int x=0;x<GRIDSIZE;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<GRIDSIZE;y++){
            float realValue=4*pressure(x,y)-pressure(x-1,y)-pressure(x+1,y)-pressure(x,y-1)-pressure(x,y+1);
            f+=abs(realValue-density(x,y));
        }
    }
    return f/GRIDSIZE/GRIDSIZE;
}
```

And finally, the update function:

```
void update(Grid &vx, Grid &vy, Grid &density, Grid &pressure, Grid &divergence){
    Grid vx0=vx.copy();
    Grid vy0=vy.copy();

    advect(vx0,vx,vx0,vy0);
    advect(vy0,vy,vx0,vy0);

    calcDivergence(density, divergence, vx, vy);

    solvePressure(divergence, pressure);

    fixDivergence(pressure, vx, vy);

    Grid density0=density.copy();
    advect(density0,density,vx,vy);

}
```

The grids are initialized as follows:

```
vx[x][y]=cos(4pi*y/GRIDSIZE)
vy[x][y]=sin(4pi*x/GRIDSIZE)
pressure[x][y]=0
density[x][y]=1 if (x/100)%2+(y/100)%2==1, otherwise 0
divergence[x][y]=0
```

GRIDSIZE is 200.

Here is the screenshot:  https://ibb.co/dmi66K

What is going wrong?

EDIT 1:
Clarification:  When you see the oddly shaped density isolines, these oscillate randomly but remain in the same position forever.

EDIT 2:
After a little while, the grid averages out to uniform density and no oscillations.

Comment: Help me make this question better instead of anonymously downvoting and closevoting.  Help fix it!

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pressure should not be sampled 2 units away, but only 1 sample away for `solvePressure`.  This prevents adjacent iterations from oscillating.

`pressureAccuracy` should pass in divergence, not density.

All of the above fixed it perfectly for me.